# Information Centric Interpretation of the Delayed Choice Experiment

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, double-slit-experiment, quantum-interpretations, measurement-problem

The photon travels from the emmitter to the detector. Along the way it bounces off a few mirrors and off or through a beam splitter or two. This journey takes time, but only from OUR perspective/frame. From the photon's point of view, it is always traveling at the speed of light. So, the same experimental setup, to the photon, undergoes (at the moment the photon is emmited from its parent atom) an instantaneous Lorentz transformation whereby the distance traveled by the photon is reduced to exactly 0. From the photon's point of view, since the distance traveled (and time elapsed) between being emitted and being absorbed are non-existent, then of course the photon knows what path it is going to take. There is never any question as to what path the photon is going to take because **there is no path**.

That's interesting, I think to myself...

The atom emitting the photon drops from an excited state to a lower energy state, one of its electrons drops down an orbital, and the aforementioned photon is emitted. From our perspective the photon flies around and does stuff for awhile before finally hitting another atom with (miracle of miracles) exactly the right amount of momentum/energy to be absorbed. But **from the photon's perspective, the two atoms were touching each other. There was no distance to be traversed**. The photon simply stepped from one atom to the next.

But wait a second, if the photon, from the photon's point of view, travels 0 meters over 0 seconds, does the photon really exist? And if the photon doesn't exist, well I guess I know how it can tell where it's going before it goes there... It's already arrived and been absorbed!

Oh no, I say to myself, I just convinced me that photons (and their accompanying pilot waves, if you're inclined to towards that particular interpretation) don't exist!  Ok, ok, ok, don't panic. Have I ever actually seen a photon? Hmmmm... I've seen (pun intended) what happens when an atom absorbs a photon, but no, if I'm being honest with myself, then no, I've never actually seen a photon. Ok... have I ever directly observed an electromagnetic wave (or a wave function for that matter)? I guess I haven't (I'm not a member of the Vienna Circle, I swear!).

Well, what the heck?!

And then the voice of John Wheeler echos through my memory. "It from bit," John says. And then Claude Shannon's paraphrasing cousin chimes in, "remember grasshopper, information requires 3 things, a sender, a channel, and a receiver."

Well gosh, I think to myself, I happen to have those three things right here. I have a sender (the atom which emits the photon), the channel (the photon's journey through the experimental setup), and a receiver (the atom that absorbs the photon at the end of its flight). There's no particle, there's no wave, there's no spooky action at a distance or superluminal communication, **there is ONLY a direct information transfer from one atom to the other.** So, [what does one atom say to the other atom?](http://theoatmeal.com/djtaf/j/5) Well, I guess it would have to be a relatively (see what I did there?) simple statement... Perhaps it would be something like, "Hey! You! Yeah, you! Like, FYI dude! I'm here and you're, like, totally way over there dude! Isn't that radical?!"

I guess maybe it depends on what kind of atoms we're talking about...

In all seriousness though, that got me to thinking. Energy is being exchanged. Information is being exchanged. [Information is energy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_in_thermodynamics_and_information_theory#Szilard's_engine), [which in turn, is mass](https://www.britannica.com/science/E-mc2-equation) (btw, no wonder information can't be transmitted superluminally, right?!). If that's the case, and if mass and energy and information must be conserved, then by gosh, the information carried by the photon might (must?) encode information about the photon's source and its subsequent journey (which, as I established earlier, never occurred, at least not from the point of view of the nonexistent particle carrying said information). And since the amount of information can be calculated from the energy exchanged, then we know how much information ([negentropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negentropy)?) is being transferred between those two atoms!

So now I'm thinking about the temperature differentials between emitting and absorbing atoms and how the greater the temperature differential, the greater amount of information being exchanged. Where do we have the greatest temperature differential I ask myself? My mind jumps to the [CMB and the surface of last scattering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmic_microwave_background), which a quick google search tells me has a surface temperature of approximately 3000K. Lower than I thought, but that's one heck of a big surface to be that hot, so that's an awful lot of information to be had... A whole universe worth, one might say.

**So, my question is, what's wrong with this interpretation of the Delayed Choice Experiment?** Obviously something must be wrong with it or it wouldn't not exist (except in my head). It seems to me each step follows logically from its predecessor AND it seems like it neatly resolves the measurement problem as a side effect (since measurement can be clearly and concisely defined as the receipt of information that has been transmitted via a channel from a sender) AND it seems like it is the first step on the road to unraveling how our entire physical existence is generated directly from information. I didn't make any drastic assumptions or introduce any new axioms or use any of that fancy math stuff...

The closest interpretation of quantum mechanics that I've been able to find was [Relational Quantum Mechanics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_quantum_mechanics). Am I just subconsciously regurgitating Carlo Rovelli? Has he weighed in on the delayed choice and double slit experiments?

Comment: I am totally with the relational picture on QM and spacetime. So if the description of a system is with respect to a certain observer, and also the spacetime has only a relational meaning, then we have to take the spacetime structure into consideration when we are talking about 'delayed' choice and 'which route'. I think before we can clearly describe 'what's spacetime', the double slit experiment will remain mysterious. For example, L. Susskind wondered, if it's a result of superposition or entanglement.

Comment: Many things are wrong here. I'll post them in different comments. See what follows.

Comment: 1) There is no " instantaneous Lorentz transformation" and nothing that can travel faster than the speed of light.

Comment: 2) Information *is not* energy, at all.

Comment: 3) Suppose there is a mirror between emission and reception of a photon. How do you conciliate the idea that both events are in direct contact with the fact that there is a mirror (and possibly much more objects and structures) between them from our point of view?

Comment: 4) Carlo Rovelli's relationism is not similar to your picture at all. It is a relationism of what observers see as real.

Comment: So you have a good imagination, a good capacity to see possible links between representation and phenomena, *but*, you need to spend much more time and efforts than 5 minutes of casual googling to see if what you get up with makes sense.

Comment: @StéphaneRollandin, regarding comment 1: I never said that anything traveled faster than the speed of light. I merely said that, from the photon's perspective, the distance and time would both appear to be 0. It we were talking about a spaceship, the same would be true (of course a spaceship cannot reach the speed of light). From our outside frame of reference, time inside the spaceship would grind to a halt and and the length of the spaceship would become 0m. From the point of view of a passenger, 0s time would pass between departure and arrival. They would arrive the same moment they left.

Comment: @StéphaneRollandin, regarding comment 2: I respectfully disagree. The physical nature of information was proposed as far back as 1929 by Leo Szilard and was shown experimentally by Shoichi Toyabe of Chuo University in Tokyo in 2010.

Comment: @StéphaneRollandin, re 3: That's the question, isn't it. Here's where things get speculative. The mirror is in the path of the photon and so influences the experiment. The resolution I propose is that the information about the mirror's placement is encoded in the amount of energy transferred to the detector. Perhaps this is an opportunity to propose an alternate setup for the experiment where the one path contains less information than the other (bounces off more mirrors or something)? Is there a difference? Does this difference correspond to the information required to navigate the path?

Comment: Only, information is not energy. The energy of a photon is given by its frequency, and this frequency does not change when it is reflected by a mirror.

Comment: @StéphaneRollandin, regarding comment 4: But what I'm proposing is relative and relational. From our perspective, the path taken by the photon is "spacelike" and so we perceive a photon traveling though space and bouncing off mirrors. But, since the photon is traveling at the speed of light, from its perspective the spacetime intervals are 0 and so considered "lightlike" or null. Isn't that a little similar?

Comment: @StéphaneRollandin, regarding the energy of the photon Pt1: I totally agree, but there is also the amount of energy transferred, which may not be exactly the same (though I'm getting the feeling you're going to disagree with me on this point). Consider the CMB radiation. The energy of the photon emitted from the surface of last scattering is 3000K. The energy of the same photon when it is absorbed in our radio telescope would be 2.725K.

Comment: @StéphaneRollandin, regarding the energy of the photon Pt2: The energy balance of 2997.275K could, in my view, be considered to be encoding information about the photon's 13.8 billion year long journey. A journey which, from the photon's perspective, is equal to 0 meters traveled over the course of 0 seconds time elapsed.

Comment: We could continue this conversation forever, but it is not the place to do so (and I do not desire to do so either). I gave you the feedback you asked for, and to me although there is some elegance in your thinking it is technically wrong. I encourage you to study this subject a little deeper, where it becomes a little less fun and involves a little more work...  Sorry about that. We have to be very harsh on our ideas in physics. We must try to kill them. If they survive, well maybe there is some truth there after all...

Comment: @StéphaneRollandin, regarding the energy of the photon Pt3: Of course, I'm taking things to the logical extreme here. At the scale of a modified delayed choice experiment, the energy differential would be MUCH lower. But would it be detectable? Perhaps... What if one path of the experimental apparatus was 1 mile longer than the other? Or, what if one path had 300 mirrors more than the other? Would you be able to detect the difference in the energy of the photons? After 300 bounces, I'm reasonably sure that radiation pressure would extract a measurable amount of momentum from the photon.

Comment: @StéphaneRollandin, regarding ideas in physics: I will continue to study physics and will attempt to gain a better understanding of our world. I encourage you to do the same and wish you luck in your future endeavors. Thank you for your feedback. It is truly appreciated.